# Best default page to use for Pingdom that isn't cached

Tags: full-page-cache

We recently had a server outage that was not reported by Pingdom. The issue was the site was fully cached and Most pages responded. It wasn't until you got into Checkout that the error surfaced.

Is there a standard non-cached page in Magento 2 that we can point Pingdon to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Magento 2, certain pages are designed as **uncacheable**, as known as non-cacheable, by marking a block on the layout with `cacheable="false"`. This action disables the **full page** cache for those pages. The following pages on the storefront are **uncachable**:

- Customer Account pages: pages related to the customer account such as login, create a new account, forgot password, order history, downloadable products, wishlist, address, and my product reviews, etc.
- Shopping Cart page
- Checkout page
- Products Comparison List page
- Contact page
- Popular Search Terms page

I recommend checking the **Popular Search Terms** page as it is the most lightweight.